# Footer doesn't stick to bottom

Tags: html, css, jsp, sticky-footer

i am working on struts2 application.when i am dealing with jsp pages one problem is occurred, when page contents are less footer float below the contents, this will look very bad.but when contents are more than page then it automatically float to the bottom.this is ok for me. Any help will be appreciated...

the code used for footer in css is...

```
#footer {
    height:41px;
    background:url(../images/main-bg.png) repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: you may want to make the footer sticky.. : refer to this tutorial http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a sticky footer (always on the bottom of the page, no matter the height of the page), use `position: fixed;`

```
   #footer {
     height:41px;
     background:url(../images/main-bg.png) repeat-x;
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 100%;
   }
```

Comment: i have already used position: fixed but the problem of using this is explained in below answer...

Comment: that problem is easily solvable: set a margin-bottom for the main content, of the same height of the footer ;) BTW i'll move footer out too, it's cleaner.

Comment: #footer {
 height:41px;
    background:url(../images/main-bg.png) repeat-x;
    position:absolute;
   margin-bottom: 41px;
 width: 100%;
} my first problem with this solution is solved, but when contents are less that is i want to print only one line, footer is came under    the line immediately any solution..

Comment: Could you create a Fiddle (jsFiddle.net) ? Try playing with `height` and `max-height`, like `max-height: 41px;` and `height: auto;` or similar

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for making the footer to be always visible on the browser window that doesn't get affected by scrolling then `position:fixed` will do. However that will look bad when the content is more and you need scrolling and still the footer stays in the viewing area overlapping the content. A clean solution is to move the footer markup outside the wrapper div. Something like should be good:

[**SAMPLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NZTTf/3/)

**CSS-**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    background-color:yellow;
    height: 90%; //sharing the height between wrapper and footer
    margin:0px;
}
#footer {
    background-color:green;
    height: 10%;
    min-height:20px;
    max-height:40px;
}
```